# What's the best way to design this structure in c?

Tags: c, struct, binary-search-tree, nodes

I need to create a binary search tree in c. Inside the tree is a list of words organized by the first letter. Each node contains the letter and a list of words(strings) beginning with that letter, as well as pointers to the other nodes. I'm not sure how I should do the list of words inside the structure. Should I create a new structure to do the list? What's the best way?

So far my structure is:

```
    typedef struct Node {
          char letter;

          //where the list of words begginning with letter should be   

          struct Node *left;
          struct Node *right;
    } Node;
```

Comment: The list of strings can be implemented as a `Linked List`, and Node will contain a pointer to the list associated to the letter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create another struct for the list that you include in the node. Then you can create separate functions to manipulate the list:

```
struct LIST {
    char *word;
    struct LIST *next;
};

typedef struct Node {
      char letter;

      struct LIST *words;

      struct Node *left;
      struct Node *right;
} Node;
```

Answer (score 0):

The secret is to do this

```
   typedef struct node
   {
      char data;
      struct node *next;
      struct node *child;
   }
```

now every route from the root to a leaf makes up a word, but we only count "child" jumps not "next" or "sibling" jumps.